# Mono - HttpWebRequest over SSL - Error writing headers

Tags: mono

The below throws a System.Net.WebException - Error:SendFailure (Error writing headers) over SSL but works fine for http://www.google.com

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace HTTPS_Headers
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("https://www.google.co.uk/?q=mono");

            using(var reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())) {

                Console.WriteLine (reader.ReadToEnd ());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this on Mono 3.4.0/Lubuntu 14.04.  Works fine over SSL on Windows/.NET 4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try running the following on your machine to import trusted root certificates:

```
mozroots --import --sync
```

Comment: if you run your program with "sudo mono", adding the certs to the user store will not be enough. You would have to add them to the machine store by passing "--machine". This took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: @knguyen - Mono 3.12, or above, has removed the need to run mozroots - http://apebox.org/wordpress/linux/1163

Comment: This still won't work for certain sites. I am having a REALLY HARD TIME sending logs through HTTPS requests to Logz.io, for instance. 

Any idea of what can I do besides this and using the ValidateCertificateCallback thing ?