# "Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httpresponse, restsharp

I'm trying to fetch data in "xamarin studio" using "rest sharp" package like so:

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://xxxx.xxxx.com");

var request = new RestRequest ("/api/external/xxxx/xxxx/", Method.GET);
request.AddParameter("username", "xxxx");
request.AddParameter("api_key", "xxxx");

request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");      
request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var response = client.Execute (request);

var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (response.Content);
```

The error I get is

> Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)

I really don't know what is wrong.
I'm using windows 7 64-bit.

Please help...
Thank you for advance!!!

Comment: Has to do with Certificates being out of synch. Linux based solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081384/mono-httpwebrequest-over-ssl-error-writing-headers

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to certificate errors. Can you test using straight HTTP? Or set your app to ignore certificate checks as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629989/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-xamarin-forms-pcl).