# Ignore SSL certificate errors in Xamarin.Forms (PCL)

Tags: ssl, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to do something like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2675183 but in Xamarin.Forms PCL App? I'm using HttpClient to connect to the server.

Answer (score 35):

`ServicePointManager` isn't defined in PCL but defined in platform specific classes.

There are `ServicePointManager` in both **Xamarin.iOS** and **Xamarin.Android** with same usage. You can reference it inside any classes in your platform projects. *However*, currently there is no such class and seems no way to do so for **Windows Phone** app.

**Example:**

```cs
// Xamarin.Android

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // You may use ServicePointManager here
        ServicePointManager
            .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}

// Xamarin.iOS

public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ServicePointManager
            .ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.  The callback never gets called and an exception is generated that says the SSL is invalid

Comment: AndroidClientHandler doesn't seem to support ServerCertificateValidationCallback. You got any updated information to handle this problem on Android?

Comment: **THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK FOR ANDROID**

Answer (score 25):

With a unique code on **Xamarin.Forms** way, instantiate a HttpClientHandler
**Example:**

```
private HttpClient _httpClient;
public HttpClient HttplicentAccount
{
    get
    {
        _httpClient = _httpClient ?? new HttpClient
        (
            new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                {
                    //bypass
                    return true;
                },
            }
            , false
        )
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("YOUR_API_BASE_ADDRESS"),
        };

        // In case you need to send an auth token...
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "YOUR_TOKEN");
        return _httpClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of all the solutions here, this one works in VS2019 for Android after the latest 2019/20 updates.

Comment: still getting the same error after applying the above code.

Comment: This worked for me with VS2022 for Android with latest updates.  I am so thankful.  I've been working on this forever and I only used this part: ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                {
                    //bypass
                    return true;
                },

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `AndroidClientHandler`, you need to supply a `SSLSocketFactory` and a custom implementation of `HostnameVerifier` with all checks disabled. To do this, you’ll need to  subclass `AndroidClientHandler` and override the appropriate methods.

```
internal class BypassHostnameVerifier : Java.Lang.Object, IHostnameVerifier
{
    public bool Verify(string hostname, ISSLSession session)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

internal class BypassSslValidationClientHandler : AndroidClientHandler
{
    protected override SSLSocketFactory ConfigureCustomSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection connection)
    {
        return SSLCertificateSocketFactory.GetInsecure(1000, null);
    }

    protected override IHostnameVerifier GetSSLHostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection connection)
    {
        return new BypassHostnameVerifier();
    }
}
```

And then

```
var handler = new BypassSslValidationClientHandler();
var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static HttpClient PreparedClient() {
 HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
 handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback+= (sender, cert, chain,sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; }; 
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler); return client; 
}

HttpClient client = PreparedClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this but with a slightly different error message:

```
Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
  at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
```

I fixed it with the following in `OnCreate (MainActivity.cs)`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

// HERE
#if DEBUG
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
#endif

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize Material Design renderer
    FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

This was the fix for Android, putting the same code in `FinishedLaunching (AppDelegate.cs)` for iOS should also work.

Answer (score 0):

- Put this line of code inside OnCreate in MainActivity.cs:
  System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

it should be like :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            // to bypass ssl
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            ...
            ..
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

- Now change var httpClient = new HttpClient();
- to: var httpClient = new HttpClient(new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler());
- And don't forget to call IP address instead of using localhost