# Xamarin.Forms Ignore SSL Errors Android (Self Signed)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

**Problem is urls with Self Signed SSL Certificates are being rejected by the `WebView` on Android resulting in a white screen.**

I understand this question has been [answered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629989/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-xamarin-forms-pcl) These solutions do not work. You can see by the comments it does not work for many others.  `ServicePointManager` will work for IOS and compile for Android but the callback will never be raised on Android resulting in the white `WebView`.

In Xamarin.Forms I have my full page `WebView`.

```
    <WebView x:Name="Browser" HeightRequest="1000" WidthRequest="1000"/>
```

In my Android project `MainActivity.cs` I have tried the suggested `ServicePointManager` which does not work. Instead in my `OnCreate` of `MainActivity.cs` I problematically add a `AddInvalidWebClient`.

```
    private void AddInvalidWebClient()
    {
        WebView wb = new WebView(this);
        wb.SetWebViewClient(new InvalidWebViewClient());
        wb.LoadUrl("https://invalidcertificate.com");
        // Not required for Invalid certificate, but required for my site.
        WebSettings ws = wb.Settings;
        ws.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        // Add our new wb.
        SetContentView(wb);
    }
```

My `InvalidWebViewCient` is very basic. It inherits standard `WebViewClient` and suppresses the SSL error.

```
    public class InvalidWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override void OnReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
        {
            handler.Proceed();
        }
    }
```

**Is there another/better way to ignore SSL Erros on `Xamarin.Forms` `WebView` for Android?** `ServicePointManager` does not work and adding another `WebView` in my `MainActivity.cs` seems counter active (not to mention hacky) for `Xamarin.Forms`.

P.S. I understand it's bad to suppress all SSL errors. Once I'm confident I have a solution I will build in a way to suppress them only for my certificates public key.

Comment: Implement your own ViewRenderer for WebView (like in the Xamarin's HybridWebView example) that contains a subclassed WebView that implements a subclassed WebViewClient that overrides OnReceivedSslError.

Comment: Use can see this link for reference https://gist.github.com/MansiShah04/2638427748d11f69aee85d22010e1f91